# How do I get multiple workspaces in Unity?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, unity, ayatana

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reduce or increase the number of workspaces in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34572/how-can-i-reduce-or-increase-the-number-of-workspaces-in-unity)

[This video](http://www.grillbar.org/wordpress/?p=494) from a Unity developer shows him clicking on the workspace button in the launcher to use multiple workspaces (aka virtual desktops). On my 2 netbooks clicking on that button only invokes the expose-like effect.

Is there a setting somewhere I can use to get this functionality, and if so, what is the keyboard shortcut to go along with it?