# Is it possible to have more than 4 desktops in Unity?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reduce or increase the number of workspaces in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34572/how-can-i-reduce-or-increase-the-number-of-workspaces-in-unity)

I currently use 6 desktops and I would like to continue to do so. I've tried Unity, but by default it has only 4 and navigation between them is clunky at best. Gnome 3 has a linear navigation scheme between desktops, but in Unity one must either go left/right or up/down and there doesn't appear to be any way of knowing which desktop one is on and which direction one needs to go. In my view, the multiple desktop scheme in Unity is very poorly designed and unecessarily limits users to the default settings. Is it possible to change the default settings?