# Can workspace switching Ctrl + Alt + Arrows be changed?

Tags: 11.04, unity

Can the workspace switcher be changed so that it works like it used to in 10?

When switching workspaces in Unity you need to use both the horizontal arrow keys, but if you want to get to workspace 3 and 4 then you must use the vertical arrow keys. This is annoying.

Can I change it so that I can access all workspaces by hitting the horizontal arrow keys only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this topic for changing the layout of the workspaces: [How can I reduce or increase the number of workspaces in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34572/how-can-i-reduce-or-increase-the-number-of-workspaces-in-unity)

Default is 2 by 2 but you can set the vertical virtual size to 1 and the horizontal virtual size  to 4 and you can use cntrl+alt+arrow left+right to go through 4 workspaces.