# Why do my windows disappear when I move them to different workspaces?

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz, workspaces

For example:

I open some file with Evince (in default workspace 1) then I right-click on window titlebar and select "Move to workspace 2"

What happens is that Evince window disappears from workspace 1, but it can't be found in any workspace. Process is running, as I can confirm with System Monitor.

In CompizConfig I can't find any option describing workspaces, to none for customizing workspaces (like don't show on Launcher if not in current workspace - but that's another story).
I can only find some settings with gconf-editor - under Metacity there is option to set number of workspaces (currently set to 4) and that's the number of workspaces shown when I click on "Workspace Switcher" icon on Launcher

So, I would like to solve this problem somehow with your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After browsing some answers like this one [How can I reduce or increase the number of workspaces in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34572/how-can-i-reduce-or-increase-the-number-of-workspaces-in-unity), I checked general options in my CompizConfig and noticed that "Number of Desktops" is set to 4.

I don't quite understand what is this number of desktops, is it for multiple monitors or what, but if I set it to 1 then my problem is gone.

---

**Note**: If this is true, then Takkat's answer in linked topic (currently second answer with 7 up-points) is 'problematic' as it would introduce my problem for those that follow it.