# How to add more workspaces in Unity?

Tags: unity, workspaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reduce or increase the number of workspaces in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34572/how-can-i-reduce-or-increase-the-number-of-workspaces-in-unity)

How can I add rows/columns to my workspaces? I would prefer a method which doesn't involve CCSM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of desktops options is non-functional & has been for quite some time so just leave alone
(it shouldn't even be there anymore & as of my current install isn't

Comment: Is there anything I can install myself to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you don't want to use CCSM. Anyway, there is indeed an alternative to CCSM to adjust the number of rows/columns in the workspaces. 
Install gconf-editor either from the software center or through the terminal using this command: 
    sudo apt-get install gconf-editor

And as the picture depicts, you can edit the hsize and vsize of the workspace you have.

[image]

Alternatively, you can change the number of workspaces through terminal.

Go to the dash and open the Terminal.
To change the number of rows, type the following command, changing the final number to the number you wish. Press Enter.

```
gconftool-2 --type=int --set /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/vsize 2
```

To change the number of columns, type the following command, changing the final number to the number you wish. Press Enter.

```
gconftool-2 --type=int --set /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/hsize 2
```

Comment: gconftool --set /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/hsize --type=int 3
gconftool --set /apps/compiz-1/general/screen0/options/vsize --type=int 3

This does essentially the same thing.  I've tried it already and no matter what I set hsize and vsize to nothing helps.

Comment: I think you also need to change the number of desktops accordingly to see the difference. Does logging out and logging in do any difference? You might also want to check out this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35488/list-of-custom-launchers-quicklists-for-unity/46832#46832) for other innovative idea to change the workspace desktops.

Comment: I've even tried restarting.  For the `number_of_desktops`, should I set it to 9 if the `hsize` and `vsize` are 3?

Comment: @Stuart After the latest update, the above method works effectively in changing the number of workspaces

Comment: I like this command line option for it enables me to create a shortcut to do that! nice.

Comment: Doesn't work in Ubuntu 13.10. Editing the settings does nothing, even after a restart. Still 2x2.

Comment: @thejoshwolfe You should be referring to [How can I reduce or increase the number of workspaces in Unity?](http://askubuntu.com/a/108306) for Ubuntu 13.10