# How can number of workspace be set used Unity in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: unity, 11.10, workspaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reduce or increase the number of workspaces in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34572/how-can-i-reduce-or-increase-the-number-of-workspaces-in-unity)

How can number of workspace be set used Unity in Ubuntu 11.10? Unfortunately, I could not find any solution for it :(.