# How can I add more workspaces?

Tags: unity, 11.10, gnome, compiz, workspaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reduce or increase the number of workspaces in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34572/how-can-i-reduce-or-increase-the-number-of-workspaces-in-unity)

I have searched and read through [other answers](https://askubuntu.com/q/34572/22537), but I couldn't find one.

I can't change then number of workspaces. Compiz desktop size in general settings doesn't work. I've tried some gconf commands, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: You need to logout and login after changing the workspaces in ccsm - you have done that?

Comment: Have you read [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/34572/22537)?

Comment: Yes dinjjl, as I said that option doesn't work for me.

And fossfreedom, I shouldn't have to do that now as It has been updated instantly before

Comment: You shouldn't "technically" need to logout, or is this more of a moral/aesthetic/user-rights issue?  (I don't know if it works, but it seems worth trying if you haven't.)  We can only do technical answers here, for the most part.

Comment: It's nothing to do with morals, rather a case of not wanting to log out each time disrupting my work-flow each time I want to make minor changes to my work environment

Comment: @alan -- Just to be clear, are you saying that it doesn't work, or that even if changes via CCSM work, you need a different method, since you can't disrupt your workflow (... every time you change the number of workspaces)?

Comment: @alan - I agree you shouldnt need to - looks like this is a new bug in 11.10 - you should file this as a bug report on launchpad.  In the interim - you will need to logout and login.

Comment: Please refer the below link

[Add workspace in ubuntu 11.10][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/68569/how-can-number-of-workspace-be-set-used-unity-in-ubuntu-11-10