# How to reset the number of workspaces?

Tags: 11.10, unity, workspaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reduce or increase the number of workspaces in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34572/how-can-i-reduce-or-increase-the-number-of-workspaces-in-unity)

For some reason my workspaces have disappeared. Looks like I only have 1, how could I reset my workspace settings for a particular account? If I login to the guest account, the workspaces work fine, but under my primary account it does not.

Comment: Are you using unity-2d or gnome-Classic & have you logged into a gnome-shell session? If so easy to fix but will keep happening after a gnome-shell login/logout

Comment: which version is it??? If <10.04 then just right lick on the panel where you have workspace switcher and you can configure the no. of workspaces..

Comment: ...And if necessary add workspace switcher to your panel before

Comment: I'm using version 11.10 with with Unity not 2d

Comment: I have got the same problem here. 11.10 GNOME 2