# How can I change the number of workspaces in workspace switcher?

Tags: workspaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reduce or increase the number of workspaces in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34572/how-can-i-reduce-or-increase-the-number-of-workspaces-in-unity)

How can I change the number of workspaces in workspace switcher using ubuntu 11.10. In ubuntu 10 there was an opportunity to set other size than 2x2. I prefer 3x3 workspaces, how can I reach this in ubuntu 11.10.

Answer (score 15):

You can install and launch the **Compiz Config Settings Manager** (if you do this from the terminal, the command is `ccsm`).

The english version of the button you have to click will probably be called "General Options":
[image]

There is a tab probably called "Desktop Size". There you can change the number of rows and columns of the workspaces.
[image]

Changing those value to 4 / 2 instead of 2 / 2 results in this:
[image]

Comment: This doesn't change anything for me. I think I remember that unity overrides this.

Comment: Well it does change for me: 11.10, unity (3D version). So I have no idea why it does not change it for you...

Comment: Interesting. I'm running the same. Do you have to logout/in or something? If I just change it in ccsm, I see no effect, still got 4 desktops.

Comment: sorry, no. no logout (though I closed ccsm after the change, but I have no clue if that does the trick). I added a screenshot "proof" :-)

Comment: Hm, 4/2 doesn't work for me either. It's not that I don't believe you! I'll look if there's a known bug somewhere.

Comment: Christoph - if you are using unity-2d then it's set in gconf, (gconf-editor), /apps/metacity/general/num_workspaces. Though be aware that atm unity-2d will only use 2 vertical

Comment: FYI, although it didn't at first work for me, it did change the setting *after a reboot*. (I also ran `ccsm` once with sudo, which didn't seem to work, but it was before the reboot).

Comment: ccsm not found on 12.04. I used sudo apt-get isntall compizconfig-settings-manager instead.