# How to change the number of workspaces in Unity?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I reduce or increase the number of workspaces in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34572/how-can-i-reduce-or-increase-the-number-of-workspaces-in-unity)

How to change the number of workspaces in Unity without installing any other softwares like MyUnity or something like that?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 Beta 2.