# How to change Menu Opacity

Tags: compiz

I know how to change the Opacity of the task bar in Unity on Ubuntu 12.10 VIA Compiz. My question is, is there a way I can change the Opacity of the Menus? See, in the image below, it shows the App Bar that it almost transparent. But, on the Calendar, it is mostly black. I would like to make it match the App Menu and all other menus.

[image: Transparent App Bar. Solid Menu's.]

Comment: The color of the menu entries is controlled by the gtk theme, so you can edit its value by changing the style of the menu bar item with the name UnityPanelWidget. 
The opacity of the menus can be changed by compiz settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the opacity from `Compiz Config Settings Manager` (install it by `sudo apt-get install ccsm`). Open CCSM and go to **Accessibility** page, Then check the `opacity brightness and saturation` option if not already checked. Then click the same button to go view its options.
In there you'll find the tab `Opacity`, in this tab clikc on the `New` button in bottom and enter the values:

```
Window: DropdownMenu
Window Rules: 75  

Window: popupmenu
Window Rules: 75  

Window: Menu
Window Rules: 75
```

and back.

Compiz might crash when you check the button but dont worry about that. Just log out then in again and unity will be fixed.

Comment: This would be a great answer if you can use `gsettings` instead of ccsm...

Comment: I'm not really sure about doing same with `gsettings` but hope someone can figure it out.

Comment: my answer here will give you some hints how to do this :) http://askubuntu.com/a/202598/14356

Comment: Thank you! I found my preferred opacity value us 90 in this case.