# Make window backgrounds semi-transparent

Tags: unity, 15.04, gtk, window

I want to make window backgrounds semi-transparent while keeping the window elements such as text and icons and other stuff(like controls) on top of it opaque. Till now, I have stumbled upon ways to make the entire window transparent, but not a part of it.

Comment: You should look for compiz config settings..

Comment: couldn't find anything relating to localized transparency in a window

Comment: opacity settings control the opacity of entire window

Comment: Not sure about icons in window but menu bar ,text can be separately set for opacity--http://askubuntu.com/questions/224865/how-to-change-menu-opacity, you can take some idea from the link. Check for opacity and brightness section in compiz official page for detailed things..

Comment: Opacity seems to have been removed from CCSM - on 16.04 it no longer appears for me.

Answer (score 1):

So, there's a package, `compizconfig-settings-manager`, which installs a program, `ccsm`.  In previous versions of Ubuntu, this included, in the "Accessibility" section, a feature, "Opacity, Brightness, and Saturation."

Now, you need to additionally install the package `compiz-plugins` in order for this to appear.

So:

- `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins`
- Then, run `ccsm`.