# How to disable application window previews rotation in Unity 3D?

Tags: unity

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with 3d unity.

When I have several windows of the same application (say Nautilus) opened and I click on its launcher (in unity app launcher bar) window previews appear offering me to select which window I want to activate.
But sometimes I can't recognize for sure which one I needed by those previews.
So I'm clicking one of them. If wrong window is activated I'm clicking the launcher again, and trying next window. But then I found that those previews changed their positions (rotated). So I can't predict those window order to iterate them all without repetition.

I would like to disable that "windows preview rotation" feature.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if it is possible, but you can use the faster <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> (or ALT+the key over TAB on your keyboard) to change windows within one application.