# How to change the number of workspaces from the command line?

Tags: unity, command-line, dconf

I'd like to change `org.compiz.profiles.unity.plugins.core` -> `hsize` and -> `vsize` from command line.

I thought I could use

```
gsettings set org.compiz.profiles.unity.plugins.core vsize 4
```

but then I've got an error message:

```
No such schema 'org.compiz.profiles.unity.plugins.core'
```

Is it possible at all? The setting can be clearly seen, as on the attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: [Reduce number of workspaces](http://askubuntu.com/q/34572/62483).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use `dconf`:

To get the current values:

```
dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/hsize
dconf read /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/vsize
```

To set new values:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/hsize 2
```

Comment: As I understand, `gsettings` is a preferred over dconf. It offers higher-level access to the dconf database. But I might be wrong.

Comment: This is only valid for application developers where the Gsettings API offers a cross platform access to the configuration database. Dconf access in your case (command line) is perfectly valid.

Comment: @SylvainPineau Maybe is getting out of the range of the initial question, but is there a way to allow Wrap-Around (if i'm at WS 1 and i go up, ill get to the last WS) through command line?

Comment: @frank you can use `dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/wall/allow-wraparound true` to enable Wrap-Around and `dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/wall/allow-wraparound` to disable it.

Comment: Any idea on how to enable or disable workspaces using dconf?

Answer (score 15):

The schema is `org.compiz.core` and it is a relocatable scheme (this makes it possible to support multiple profiles for Compiz).

For relocatable schemes you have to add the path if you use `gsettings`. It's `/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/` for the Compiz profile `unity`:

```
gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ hsize 4
gsettings set org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ vsize 4
```