# Workspaces don't work on my system

Tags: unity, 11.10, compiz, workspaces

It shows only one workspace when I click on workspaces icon, what should I do?

Comment: Is this a fresh install? If this happens in a fresh install then it is surely a bug

Comment: has this problem been solved? Can you confirm?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Get Compiz Config Settings Manager

Install the package `compizconfig-settings-manager` [image: install ccsm]

**Via Command Line:**

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

**Via Software Center:**

Or you can install it via Software Center. Open Dash and type `software` which will show **Software Center`**

[image: Opening Software Center via Unity Dash]

When Software Center is opened then search for `compiz` on the top-right hand side

[image: Searching for ccsm in Software Center]

In my case it shows **Remove** since I have it installed. In yours it will show **Install**. Just go ahead and install it. If a password is asked, enter the password you use to login to Ubuntu.

#### Open Compiz Config Settings Manager or `ccsm`

Then open Dash and search for `ccsm`

[image: How to open ccsm from Unity Dash]

After CCSM has opened.

[image]

Select **General Options**. It is in the second row

After you click on General options, select the last tab named **Desktop Size**

[image]

Now check the **Horizontal Virtual Size** and **Vertical Virtual Size**

In my case both are **2**, so I have **4 workplaces** 2X2

In your case it would be 1. Increment and make it 2 and then click on **Launcher > Workplaces** icon. The changes should be reflected

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem after upgrading from 11.04 to 11.10 and compiz settings don't reflect even after rebooting. I had 5 workspaces before upgrading, now I have just one :(

This method works for me: [How do I get multiple workspaces in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2792/how-do-i-get-multiple-workspaces-in-unity)